# How to emulate in Java the behavior of RPG Z-ADD or other assignment that would be an overflow?

Tags: java, rpgle, rpg

I have to mimic RPG behavior in Java.  In RPG, there are 2 zoned decimal fields
FLDA is length 2 with 0 decimals
FLDB is length 5 with 1 decimals
FLDA value = 0
FLDB value = 1234.5

RPG line of code

```
 C                     Z-ADDFLDB      FLDA
```

FLDA value would then be 34.  By default RPG does not throw an overflow exception, it truncates to fit.

How can I do this with Java BigDecimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of RPG had this design flaw...RPG IV corrects it when using either the `EVAL` op-code or the `TRUNCNBR(*NO)` compiler option.

You're going to need to write Java equivalents of RPG's `ADD`, `SUB`, `Z-ADD` and `Z-SUB` op-codes.  `MOVE` would be another problematic op-code.